# QLabel "break" word if too long

Tags: c++, string, qt, widget, label

are there ways to allow `QLabel` breaks words if those words are too long? I've seen

```
q_label->setWordWrap(true)
```

but it works with spaces, but if a single word is too long, then it will overflow...
I would like something like `word-break: break-all` for web development

I've also seen `QTextDocument` but it does not allow to have a fixed width and a not-fixed height

Comment: _`QTextDocument` does not allow to have a fixed width and a not-fixed height_ How about [QWidget::setSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setSizePolicy-1)?

Comment: You can create your own label and in the `paintEvent()` method, use `drawText()` with `Qt::TextWrapAnywhere` flags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just put `Zero-width space` between each `char`

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
text = "TheBrownFoxJumpedOverTheLazyDog"
label.setWordWrap(True)
label.setText("\u200b".join(text))  # The magic is here.
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

## Or you can write your own `QLabel`

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class HumanLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text: str = "", parent: QtWidgets.QWidget = None):
        super().__init__("\u200b".join(text), parent)
        self.setWordWrap(True)

    def setText(self, arg__1: str) -> None:
        super().setText("\u200b".join(arg__1))

    def text(self) -> str:
        return super().text().replace("\u200b", "")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
text = "TheBrownFoxJumpedOverTheLazyDog"
label = HumanLabel(text)
assert label.text() == text
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

[Wikipedia: Zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no out-of-the-box way to automatically break words into several line for `QLabel`.

You may code to or manually insert line break or space in your text at a fixed length, so `QLabel::setWordWrap()` could work properly.

```cpp
QLabel *pLabel = new QLabel(this);
pLabel->setText("first line\nsecond line\nthird line\n");
pLabel->setWordWrap(true);
```

You could also use [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html). Its `setDefaultTextOption` method allows you to set a [QTextOption](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html). And `QTextOption::setWrapMode(QTextOption::WrapAnywhere)` allows to wrap text at any point on a line.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that adds a space every time a word is larger than the maximum size of the label. If you want to limit the word length in character count, this should work:

```cpp
void wrapLabelByCharCount(QLabel *label, int characterCount)
{
    QString text = label->text();
    int wordLength = 0;
    bool insideWord = false;
    QFontMetrics fontMetrics(label->font());
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\t' || text[i] == '\n')
            insideWord = false;
        else
        {
            if (!insideWord)
            {
                insideWord = true;
                wordLength = 0;
            }
            ++wordLength;
        }
        if (wordLength > characterCount)
        {
            text = text.left(i) + "\n" + text.right(text.length() - i);
            label->setFixedHeight(label->height() + fontMetrics.height());
            insideWord = false;
        }
    }
    label->setText(text);
}
```

And you should use this if you want to wrap the word based on a fixed pixel width:

```cpp
void wrapLabelByTextSize(QLabel *label, int widthInPixels)
{
    QString text = label->text();
    QString word = "";
    bool insideWord = false;
    QFontMetrics fontMetrics(label->font());
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ' || text[i] == '\t' || text[i] == '\n')
            insideWord = false;
        else
        {
            if (!insideWord)
            {
                insideWord = true;
                word = "";
            }
            word += text[i];
        }
        if (fontMetrics.horizontalAdvance(word) > widthInPixels)
        {
            text = text.left(i) + "\n" + text.right(text.length() - i);
            label->setFixedHeight(label->height() + fontMetrics.height());
            insideWord = false;
        }
    }
    label->setText(text);
}
```

Here are some examples of how to use these:

```cpp
q_label->setWordWrap(true); //required for this to work
wrapLabelByCharCount(q_label, 15); // wraps all words that have more than 15 characters
wrapLabelByTextSize(q_label, q_label->width()); // wraps words that exceed the width of your label (this is probably the one you want)
wrapLabelByTextSize(q_label, 25); // wraps words that exceed 25 pixels
```

**EDIT:** It is important to note that these functions will not resize the label for text wrapped by QLabel's default word wrapper (which would also require reimplementing it in order to count the number of wraps). You should make sure the label is big enough to fit all the text.

Answer (score 0):

## TextWrapAnywhere QLabel

Subclass `QLabel` and and implement the `paintEvent`, where you can set the text alignment to `TextWrapAnywhere` when you `drawItemText`.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262123/qlabel-word-wrap-mode/68891355#68891355) for an example in pyqt5.

Comment: I've implemented that in C++: `style()->drawItemText(&p, rect(), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::TextWrapAnywhere, palette(), true, text());` however it does not seem to change anything

Comment: I haven't implemented it c++, but it should work as long as pyqt works.

Answer (score 0):

`Qt` only supports a subset of `HTML` which does not contain `word-break`. Or the solution will be extremely simple.

But there is also a workaround with `QTextBrowser`. It inherits from `QTextEdit`, and in read-only mode. The `QTextDocument` in the `QTextBrowser` does the trick.

```
QTextBrowser tb = new QTextBrowser(parent);
QTextOption opt;
opt.setWrapMode(QTextOption::WrapAnywhere); // like word-break: break-all
tb->document()->setDefaultTextOption(opt);
tb->setStyleSheet("border: none;"); // no border
tb->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarPolicy::ScrollBarAlwaysOff); // no vertical scroller bar
tb->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarPolicy::ScrollBarAlwaysOff); // no horizontal scroller bar
```