# QLabel setMinimumHeight After Custom WordWrap Qt.TextWrapAnywhere PyQt5 ( Full responsive With/Without Emoji )

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, word-wrap, qlabel

I want **Qt.TextWrapAnywhere** for my QLabel in a Layout.

I followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262123/qlabel-word-wrap-mode/68891355#68891355) instruction.My code is also same to give a minimal code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QStyleOption, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStyle

class SuperQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuperQLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.textalignment = Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.TextWrapAnywhere
        self.isTextLabel = True
        self.align = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)

        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)

        self.style().drawItemText(painter, self.rect(),
                                  self.textalignment, self.palette(), True, self.text())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(100, 200)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setText("11111111111111111111\n2222222211111111")

        self.slabel = SuperQLabel()
        self.slabel.setMinimumWidth(10)
        self.slabel.setText("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.slabel)

        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.mainlayout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I changed little bit that code **self.slabel.setMinimumWidth(10)** otherwise resizing Label according to width wont work.

It is perfectly wrapping the text according to width.But the Problem is when height is considered **self.label = QLabel()** Normal QLabel auto adjust height according to content with layout.

For example if i add one **\n** with text that means Qlabel must show 2 lines.

But with this new Custom Label e.g.**self.slabel = SuperQLabel()**  wrapping is good as long as there is space for height in layout.
I think i have to use **setminimumHeight()** but dont know how to get proper height after custom wrapping.

Comment: If you add a new line, you're using the rich text engine, which creates known [layout problems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues). This makes the proposed solution work inconsistently. Setting a minimum height might help, but it should be done carefully.

Comment: How to do that?Can you send any type of hints @musicamante

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't achieve a resize function that respects *both* width and height and *also* sets a minimum size in both dimensions. That's a limit that cannot be addressed in any way due to the way layouts work. The only option you have is to override [`heightForWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#heightForWidth) which will only update the hint, but can *not* force a dimension. In other words, the user will *always* be able to resize the label to a width/height that will partially hide some text.

Comment: I am using Qpainter for WrapAnywhere to work.So is there any way to detect how much length of word is transferred to nextline.can we use QFontmatrics?

Comment: You're missing the point. The problem is not the painting (which just *paints*, doesn't control the size), but the size restraints. If you decrease the width of the label, it would theoretically force a minimum height, but that prevents further adjustments, and you cannot, for instance, try to resize the label to a smaller height hoping that it would then make the label wider. There's no way to know if the user (or the layout) asks specifically for a horizontal or vertical resizing, as it could be both, and it's impossible to "decide" which dimension consider as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the label is shown in a scroll area (which will not create issues with the top level layout), a better solution is to use a QTextEdit subclass, with the following configuration:

- `readOnly` must be True;
- scroll bars are disabled;
- the vertical size policy must be `Preferred` (and not `Expanding`);
- both `minimumSizeHint()` and `sizeHint()` should use the internal QTextDocument to return a proper height, with a minimum default width;
- any change in size or contents must trigger [`updateGeometry()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry) so that the parent layout will know that the hint has changed and geometries could be computed again;
- the hint *must* include possible decorations of the scroll area (which is a QFrame);

This allows avoiding the `paintEvent()` override, and provide a better and easier implementation of the size mechanism due to the features provided by QTextDocument, while minimizing the possibility of recursion to an acceptable level.

```py
class WrapLabel(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, text=''):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            WrapLabel {
                border: 1px outset palette(dark);
                border-radius: 8px;
                background: palette(light);
            }
        ''')
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.updateGeometry)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        doc = self.document().clone()
        doc.setTextWidth(self.viewport().width())
        height = doc.size().height()
        height += self.frameWidth() * 2
        return QtCore.QSize(50, height)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateGeometry()


class ChatTest(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.messages = []

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setWidget(container)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.resize(480, 360)

        for i in range(1, 11):
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000 * i, lambda:
                self.addMessage('1' * randrange(100, 250)))

    def addMessage(self, text):
        self.widget().layout().addWidget(WrapLabel(text))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.scrollToBottom)

    def scrollToBottom(self):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
            self.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
```

### Update: HTML and QTextDocument

When using `setHtml()` and `setDocument()`, the source could have `pre` formatted text that doesn't allow wrapping. To avoid that, it's necessary to iterate through all [QTextBlocks](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblock.html) of the document, get their [QTextBlockFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html), check the [`nonBreakableLines()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextblockformat.html#nonBreakableLines) property and eventually set it to `False` and set the format back with a [QTextCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html).

```
class WrapLabel(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        super().__init__()
        if isinstance(text, str):
            if Qt.mightBeRichText(text):
                self.setHtml(text)
            else:
                self.setPlainText(text)
        elif isinstance(text, QtGui.QTextDocument):
            self.setDocument(text)
        # ...

    def setHtml(self, html):
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        doc.setHtml(html)
        self.setDocument(doc)

    def setDocument(self, doc):
        doc = doc.clone()
        tb = doc.begin() # start a QTextBlock iterator
        while tb.isValid():
            fmt = tb.blockFormat()
            if fmt.nonBreakableLines():
                fmt.setNonBreakableLines(False)
                # create a QTextCursor for the current text block,
                # then set the updated format to override the wrap
                tc = QtGui.QTextCursor(tb)
                tc.setBlockFormat(fmt)
            tb = tb.next()
        super().setDocument(doc)
```

Be aware, though, that this could not be enough whenever objects with predefined or minimum width are used: images and tables. The result will be that if the object is larger than the available space, it will be cropped on its right (or left for RightToLeft text layouts).

Comment: wrapping is very good in case of normal writing.But it does not maintain with a pre formatted Text taken from another QTextedit. or simply set document of another QTextedit used for typing in a chat application.

Comment: After some testing ,I tried setting `setPlainText()` method instead of passing text in constructor ,It works.But what about if I want to set Document of another Qtextedit,because document normally take colors of copied text which is very attractive.

Comment: [`QTextEdit.setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) and [`QTextDocument.setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#setHtml) or [`QTextEdit.setDocument()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop).

Comment: No,wrapping doesn't work with setting Document  of a another QtextEdit.

Comment: @Hacker6914 It *should* work, I just tested it and it wraps as expected. Can you provide an actual example of a document that doesn't wrap?

Comment: Sorry i was busy so i couldn't post Example for You. Now i posted Example in my Question ,please check,if the given text successfully wrapped or not! and also type manually random long text and see the difference .

Comment: @Hacker6914 please don't edit the question including code for the answer, as it makes it *very* confusing. Also, you didn't need to post all that, you could have just pointed out that the problem was selecting pre-formatted text (which I didn't consider, and I'm trying to understand how to work around it), since the issue is related to *this* answer, not your original post.

Comment: My intention was to make u properly understand the issue.After u got the point ,i had planned to remove that and i cant post in the comment section,so i posted in original post.                                                                                                                Anyway ,very warm thanks to u. I am marking this as Correct Answer.

Answer (score 1):

After Some Research,I successfully fixed it.
There is a trick

**This is Full Responsive With/Without Emoji**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter,QFontMetrics,QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QStyleOption, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QStyle
import math
class SuperQLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SuperQLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.textalignment = Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.TextWrapAnywhere
        self.isTextLabel = True
        self.align = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)

        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, painter, self)

        self.style().drawItemText(painter, self.rect(),
                                  self.textalignment, self.palette(), True, self.text())
        
        fm=QFontMetrics(self.font())
        #To get unicode in Text if using Emoji(Optional)
        string_unicode = self.text().encode("unicode_escape").decode()
        ##To remove emoji/unicode from text while calculating
        string_encode = self.text().encode("ascii", "ignore")
        string_decode = string_encode.decode()
        #If Unicode/Emoji is Used
        if string_unicode.count("\\U0001") > 0:
            height=fm.boundingRect(self.rect(),Qt.TextWordWrap,string_decode).height()+1
            # +1 is varrying according to Different font .SO set different value and test.
        else:
            height=fm.boundingRect(self.rect(),Qt.TextWordWrap,string_decode).height()
        row=math.ceil(fm.horizontalAdvance(self.text())/self.width())
        self.setMinimumHeight(row*height)
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(100, 200)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.label.setText("11111111111111111111\n2222222211111111")
        self.emoji_font = QFont("Segoe UI Emoji",15,0,False)
        self.emoji_font.setBold(True)
        self.slabel = SuperQLabel()
        self.slabel.setMinimumWidth(10)
        self.slabel.setStyleSheet("background:green;")
        self.slabel.setFont(self.emoji_font)
        ########### Plain Text ######################
        # self.slabel.setText("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111")
        ####################    Or Using Emoji ############
        self.slabel.setText("111111111111111111111ABCDDWAEQQ1111111111111111111111111111wqewqgdfgdfhyhtyhy11111111111111111111111111111111111111")
        
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.mainlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.mainlayout.addWidget(self.slabel)

        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.mainlayout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's *not* a good solution, for two important reasons: 1. geometry changes should ***NEVER*** happen inside a paint event, as they can cause recursion; 2. it doesn't solve the problem with complex layouts and inconsistent minimum width/height (as already explained in my comment), since in order to make the window shorter the user must *first* make it wider, which is a serious problem for non opaque resizing and could cause *another* recursion by making the UI unusable or unresizable if widgets with specific size restraints are in the layout (like a QSplitter).

Comment: yes there r some problem ,i am trying to fix. but recursion does not arise in my case,i am making a chat application.have u looked the output with resizing.

Comment: You can *never* be sure, it doesn't happen in *your computer*, *right now*, *with the current test cases*, *with your current configuration*. At least 2 or 3 cycles of recursion will certainly be called, and that's because calling `setMinimumHeight` causes a resizeEvent that automatically schedules a repaint, which will then force a further computation that will potentially trigger the whole layout (then, further repainting, and so on). You should consider an approach with objects that better fit your requirement. Applications like yours normally use the Graphics Framework, not widgets.

Comment: I wonder Qtextedit will be good for this.

Comment: QTextEdit might be a better solution, as it already provides wrap options natively so you don't need to override painting; if you're always using it inside a scroll area, then, it can be safe to update the minimum size hint of the widget, as it will minimize the possibility of recursion (especially if using a basic box layout).

Comment: but the problem when i copy and pasting something then horizontal scrollbar shows up.how to adjust it's document's width as widget's width?wrapping should done vertically because i want to fix the width of qtextedit

Comment: You must properly configure the QTextEdit in order to avoid scroll bars and keep the height to the minimum acceptable size. See my answer.