# PySide2 QTextEdit doesn't adjust to it's own content when using wrapping. (Making chat window)

Tags: python, pyqt, chat, pyside2, qtextedit

The PySide2 QTextEdit doesn't change it's own size when the text is placed in.

I'm trying to create something like chat window, where every message - QTextEdit in OnlyRead mode. All the 'messages' placed in QScrollArea. The main goal is to let message-boxes (message-boxeslike on the screen below) adjust their size to content.
[wrong working example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dB9Y.png)

I tried this code
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408239/Как-сделать-двухсторонний-чат-в-qt-pyqt/1408264#1408264](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1408239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2-qt-pyqt/1408264#1408264)

which has been copy-pasted lots of times. But it doesn't do what i want. It creates a fixed, no resizable QTextEdit message-boxes.

As example what i actually mean, if we have a single-word message, QTextEdit widget must become a single stroke box, with width of the message. If we have a multi-sentences message, QTextEdit widget must become a multi-stroke box (already expanded in height, without the need to scroll it inside), with maximum constant length(which i ll choose).

Next is the example with correct messages displaying
 [(good example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoYHO.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "resizable"? The code you're providing (which, by the way, is completely based on [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757504)) already does that: it resizes the content based on the text *and* the available size, and eventually wraps text whenever required.

Comment: @musicamante Finnaly i've met you, the example author. Pls help with ideas т_т. I actually dont understand how can QTextEdit adjust to contents. In your example QTextEdit just adds in ScrollArea and sizes to width of the whole window, but i need to stop sizing message when it reaches 100px (as example) and wrap the word to the next line, so, message should looks like rectangle, which doesn't expand to the whole window width and stay not more than 100px width. But when i have small message, which ll be less than 100px, QTextEdit should become smaller, like  message width.

Comment: @musicamante Where can i find info about overriding minimumSizeHint, SizeHint and ResizeEvent functions?

Comment: If your only requirement is to limit the width to 100px, then change the return value of `minimumSizeHint()` to `return QtCore.QSize(100, height)`. All the info you need is in the documentation: [`minimumSizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop), [`sizeHint()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) and [`resizeEvent()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent). Remember that those are all *virtual* methods, which can be overridden in subclasses, and each class can override them (which is what happens for QTextEdit and the inherited QAbstractScrollArea).

Comment: Be aware that, as explained in the comments to that original question, there are important issues regarding item resizing according to its contents whenever the content's aspect ratio might change on the fly. This is a common issue with layout managers (not only for Qt), as the size *hints* might change depending on *sibling* and parent items (which is what happens on scroll areas, due to the fact that scroll bars can change the size of the internal viewport, and eventually cause recursion). There is no "final" solution, you have to find your own workaround depending on your needs.

Comment: @musicamante thank you very mich for your answers! I tried to change minimumSizeHint return value, but it doesn't work. All what i can do, that's increase the width value, but can't decrease. It always stay to the width of the window and never drops smaller.

Comment: @musicamante i don't know, but my comments disappear sometimes. btw, i wanted to say thank you for all your help. i really appreciate this. (i have one more question. as i understood, there is no possibility to add margins inside QTextEdit because of it's resizing? may be i should place QTextEdit in a Frame and add margin to frame? )

Comment: If you want to add margins, you either do that (and properly) in the stylesheet, or you set them for the text edit's `textDocument()`, through [`setDocumentMargin()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop). Note that adding margins with stylesheets might change the result of `minimumSizeHint()`, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @musicamante thank you very much again!!! it works again))) (sorry for ping in comments. i actually cant make any questions in 4 days on stackoverflow Т-Т. btw, i want to ask you the question at last (i hope) time. is it possible to create a transparent window, with blur desktop effect? I tried to use QGraphicsBlurEffect with transparency, But only app's window content going to be blurred instead of desktop under the app. Is it actually possible to make that? (thank u very much again!!))

Comment: Not directly from Qt, as it completely depends on the OS, but see this https://github.com/Peticali/PythonBlurBehind

Comment: @musicamante omg. That's the golden nugget! Actually, it does, what i want. (have some lag, but still perfect!) Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don't use comments for off topic questions. If you can't ask new questions yet, please wait until you can. Btw, I cannot answer just by looking at the code, since I wouldn't know what the question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement a self-adjusting message, some precautions are required.

As explained in my answer and comments to the [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757504), you must consider the complex and delicate relation between the dimensions of a layout and its requirement, which becomes even more complex as a *text layout* doesn't have a fixed ratio.

The main problem with setting the width based on the text is that it can change the height required to display it, which can cause a recursion, and since the size is based on the *current* viewport size, the result is that the `minimumSizeHint()` will always return the smallest possible size after a certain amount of recursive calls.

Considering the above, we must do the following changes to my original code:

- the scroll area must always set a maximum width to its message widgets, possibly with a specified margin (for sent/received distinction) whenever the view is resized;
- widgets must be added to the layout with an *alignment* argument;
- the `minimumSizeHint()` must be changed to:

  1. compute the *preferred* text width ([`idealWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#idealWidth) based on the maximum size of the widget;
  2. get the reference height for that text width;
  3. set the text width to the *current* width;
  4. compare the new document height with the previous one, if they are the same it means that we can use the new width as maximum width for the hint (the text can be shorter), otherwise we use the initial text width based on the maximum size;

Note that there are a couple of differences from the modified code of your link: most importantly, rewriting the stylesheet doesn't make a lot of sense, and setting the margin creates an issue with the value returned by `frameWidth()` (that's why they subtracted 100 from the document height); that is certainly not a good choice, as the margin should be set within the layout.

```py
class WrapLabel(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, text=''):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.setReadOnly(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.updateGeometry)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        margin = self.frameWidth() * 2
        doc = self.document().clone()
        doc.setTextWidth(self.maximumWidth())
        idealWidth = doc.idealWidth()
        idealHeight = doc.size().height()
        doc.setTextWidth(self.viewport().width())
        if doc.size().height() == idealHeight:
            idealWidth = doc.idealWidth()
        return QtCore.QSize(
            max(50, idealWidth + margin), 
            doc.size().height() + margin)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateGeometry()


class ChatTest(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.margin = 100
        self.marginRatio = .8
        self.messages = []

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setWidget(container)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.resize(480, 360)

        letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz       '
        for i in range(1, 11):
            msg = ''.join(choice(letters) for i in range(randrange(10, 250)))
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500 * i, lambda msg=msg, i=i:
                self.addMessage(msg, i & 1))

    def addMessage(self, text, sent=False):
        message = WrapLabel(text)
        message.setStyleSheet('''
            WrapLabel {{
                border: 1px outset palette(dark);
                border-radius: 8px;
                background: {};
            }}
        '''.format(
            '#fff8c7' if sent else '#ceffbd')
        )
        self.messages.append(message)
        self.widget().layout().addWidget(message, 
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight if sent else QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.scrollToBottom)

    def scrollToBottom(self):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
            self.verticalScrollBar().maximum())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        sb = self.verticalScrollBar()
        atMaximum = sb.value() == sb.maximum()
        maxWidth = max(self.width() * self.marginRatio, 
            self.width() - self.margin) - sb.sizeHint().width()
        for message in self.messages:
            message.setMaximumWidth(maxWidth)
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        if atMaximum:
            sb.setValue(sb.maximum())
```