Layout ignoring sizeHints when QLabel with text wrap is present
As part of one of the Qt applications I maintain, a weird layout issue started happening after a recent update to the code.
Our dialog has multiple widgets, including some text and scroll area, and completely ignores our main widget's size hint once we set one of the QLabels to wordWrap.
I have managed to reproduce 2 cases with very minimal code:
Case1: QLabel + AddStretch
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets  # Same results with PySide6


class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a fairly long sentence, although not that long')
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)  # Comment out for expected results

        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addStretch()
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 500)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    window.setLayout(layout)

    notes_panel = MyWidget()
    layout.addWidget(notes_panel)

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Expected Result: 500x500, as per the size hint

Result, when wordWrap is set:

From the debugging I've done, my layout now has "hasHeightForWidth", which causes it to run the equivalent of heightForWidth(sizeHint.width()), and display wrong.
Case 2: A Label and a QScrollArea
Closer to my real application, we have a QScrollArea. There is a ScrollArea helper we generally use as it usually gives us better results, I'm including it here.
class MyWidget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget2, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a fairly long sentence, although not that long')
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # scroll area
        scroll = ScrollArea()
        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        for i in range(75):
            scroll.addWidget(QtWidgets.QCheckBox(str(i)))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 500)


class ScrollArea(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    """ Convenience class for setting up Scroll Areas"""
    def __init__(self, direction=QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent=None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        direction: QtCore.Qt.Vertical or QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, optional
        parent: QtWidgets.QWidget, optional
        """
        super(ScrollArea, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        layout_class = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout if direction == QtCore.Qt.Vertical else QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout
        # Create components
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget_layout = layout_class()
        self.contents_layout = layout_class()
        # Assign components
        widget_layout.addLayout(self.contents_layout)
        widget_layout.addStretch()
        widget.setLayout(widget_layout)
        self.setWidget(widget)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

    def addWidget(self, widget):
        """ Add a widget to the scroll area """
        self.contents_layout.addWidget(widget)

    def addWidgets(self, widgets):
        """ Add multiple widgets to the scroll area"""
        for widget in widgets:
            self.addWidget(widget)

    def sizeHint(self):
        """ Overriden sizeHint to return the hint based on content, plus some margins to accommodate scroll bars. """
        return self.contents_layout.sizeHint() + QtCore.QSize(30, 20)

Expected:

Result when setWordWrap(True):

This is particularly bad as I can't resize this dialog smaller, it's behaving as if the ScrollArea's sizeHint was a minimum size. This is what is happening in our application.
Note: It behaves better in PySide6, where it doesn't behave as if it was a minimum size, but the initial size still shows larger than the desired sizeHint.
I have found a few ways to get around the scroll area's sizeHint behaving as a minimum size, but I have not found any way to have both a word-wrapped label AND respect my widget's sizeHint.
I am aware that the docs mention wordWrapped labels can cause issues https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html#layout-issues and I have found other stack overflow posts with related topics, but they either have no answer or the answers do not help with finding a workaround.
qlabel has wrong sizeHint() when wordwrap is enabled
Why does enabling word wrap for a QLabel alter the layout?
Setting word wrap on QLabel breaks size constrains for the window
My questions are:

Is there a workaround so that my widget initially displays at the desired size, while still being resizeable? (Equivalent to SizePolicy.Preferred)
Is this a Qt Bug that I should report or a desired behaviour?


I cannot reproduce the second issue, neither with Qt 5.15 or 6.6.1, on Linux. What OS/Qt (not PySide) versions are you using? The first issue can be easily solved by overriding hasHeightForWidth() and returning False.

Thanks for trying. I'm on Windows 10 (same behavior on Windows 11). I don't have a standalone Qt installed, only the one shipped with PySide2, and using PySide2 5.15.2.1. Regarding the hasHeightForWidth, on which widget would you reimplement it?

Similarly to PyQt, the PySide version doesn't always match the Qt version it's actually using. For PySide, use QtCore.__version__. In any case, this seems a bug, and it looks like that the minimumSizeHint() (which by default calls the layout's minimumSize()) is wrongly computed. I've tested with PyQt (but that won't change anything) with Qt 5.15.2, with MyWidget2 both as top level window and as child, the size hint is still respected, so it may be a platform issue or a styling one. Can you try if adding app.setStyle('fusion') (right after creating the QApplication) changes anything?

In any case, a possible workaround could be to override minimumSizeHint() of the parent widget (the one containing the label and scroll area) if that widget is a child itself, otherwise try to explicitly call setMinimumHeight(500) (or even less, but still greater than 0). The hasHeightForWidth() should be set on the widget for which the layout hint creates issues, which in your case should be MyWidget (or MyWidget2). That's because, by default, it calls the related functions of the layout (if any is set, otherwise it uses that provided by the size policy, IIRC).

Thanks so much for looking into it again.
I'm also thinking there is a bug somewhere though I can't put my finger on it exactly.  I have tried on my home PC with the same versions of PySide (I checked, Qtcore.version, it is indeed 5.15.2) and got the same behaviour.
I have tried your suggestion of trying the fusion style and didn't see a difference. I have tried to implement minimumSizeHint() but it seems ignored.  Reimplementing hasHeightForWidth on my widget and returning False does the trick rather nicely, fixing all the problems I'm having here.

I forgot to ask: do you use font scaling or High DPI? What is the physical resolution (actual pixels) of the screen? You can check the DPI condition by using the QScreen functions, if you want to investigate more. It is possible that I wasn't able to reproduce the second issue due to the fact that I don't use high DPI, while the bug may be related to that.

I don't use high DPI either, however my screen is unusually large, I use a 4K 42" monitor, without any scaling on it. I don't know if a large size by itself might be enough to trigger the bug, I should try on one of the PCs with smaller screens next time I head to the office.

I am experiencing the same behaviour with Qt 5.15.2 on Windows 11, ordinary 1920x1080 monitor without scaling. Thanks for the workaround, Erwan. It fixes the height constraint, but I noticed that sometimes a long label can also cause a width constraint. If I find another workaround I will post it as an answer here.

If you have a reproduction case for that I'd be curious to see. I ended up not reporting as a bug because it's working fine for me in Qt6, meaning the bug seems already fixed.

Thanks to the comments by @musicamante I have found a solution that works.
It seems that my re-implemented sizeHint is ignored because the widget has height for width, so also re-implementing hasSizeForWidth() prevents the parent layout from re-calculating the height and properly uses my sizehint:
 class MyWidget2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget2, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('This is a fairly long sentence, although not that long')
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)

        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # scroll area
        scroll = ScrollArea()
        layout.addWidget(scroll)

        for i in range(75):
            scroll.addWidget(QtWidgets.QCheckBox(str(i)))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 500)

    # NEW METHOD
    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        return False


To put the issue plainly: In Qt 5.15.2 on Windows, if you have a QLabel on a layout, setting its wordWrap to True sets the layout’s minimum height way over what it should be. Any attempt to adjust the size or override sizeHint on either a label descendant or a widget containing it has no effect, unless you override hasHeightForWidth to return False. That prevents the widget from dynamically adjusting its height to adapt to the label’s changing line count.
The best solution is to update Qt.
If your program needs to work with 5.15.2, below is a workaround based on musicamante’s WrapLabel widget in an answer to a different question. The widget keeps a QTextDocument without displaying it, and uses it to calculate the height needed.
class WrappedLabel(QWidget):
    """Workaround for word-wrapped QLabel size constraint bug.
Adapted from musicamante https://stackoverflow.com/a/70757504/18396947"""
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        lyt = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel(text)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        lyt.addWidget(self.label)
        lyt.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lyt.setSpacing(0)
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.doc = QTextDocument(text, self)
        self.doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
        self.doc.setDefaultFont(self.label.font())

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        self.doc.setTextWidth(self.label.width())
        height = self.doc.size().height()
        height += self.label.frameWidth() * 2
        return QSize(50, height)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.minimumSizeHint()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def hasHeightForWidth(self):
        """Without this, the sizeHint seems to be ignored"""
        return False


Nice, that's a good workaround to have as well. I'll keep the other answer as accepted as this one does more than what I needed, where the height of the label was irrelevant.
